# Add DataTable with sort in html doc

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

I would like to create an simple table in html doc. The table exists but I cant order and operate with the table. I'm a noob in html and js.
My result:

[image]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/datatables.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/datatables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display">
<thead>
  <tr><th>Person</th><th>Monthly pay</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr><td>Jan Molby</td><td>12</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Steve Nicol</td><td>8</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Steve McMahon</td><td>9</td></tr>
  <tr><td>John Barnes</td><td>15</td></tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
  <tr><td>TOTAL</td><td>£45,000</td></tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example').dataTable();
  } );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are missing few things.

Like correct path to your CSS and JavaScript for your `DataTable`

You can use directly the **CDN** for `DataTable`, also don't forget to add the CDN for `jQuery`.

You can get the `DataTable` CDN from here [DataTable CDN Link](https://cdn.datatables.net/)

Check below the sample code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Person</th>
      <th>Monthly pay</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jan Molby</td>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Steve Nicol</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Steve McMahon</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John Barnes</td>
      <td>15</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>TOTAL</td>
      <td>£45,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you do something like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]]
    } );
} );
```

Make sure you have added below two JS:

> ```
> https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js
> https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
> ```

And CSS file:

> https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css

Documentation: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html

Comment: I added my result page. I did what did you say but I sill have the same results

Comment: @MartinFacts Make sure CSS and JS added in right order as mention in documentation.